# alarm(int) doesn't work in a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, signals, alarm

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
signal(SIGALRM,handler);
alarm(1);
while(1){}
```

The `handler` function just prints "test".

`alarm(1)` will eventually be executed only one time in this case. I tried to put it in the loop and it seems that it doesn't get executed at all!

I am kinda new to signals. Can someone explains to me how this happens?

Comment: If you put the call to `alarm` in the loop, you'll continually reset it to 1 second, and it will never have a chance to run down.  If you want a periodic timer, you might look into `setitimer` or `timer_create`.

Comment: Next time, consider providing a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the very least, show the code you ask about, instead of showing other code and explaining how it is different from the code which puzzles you... Also, reading docs about the function you are asking about, and mentioning how you didn't find answer there is a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just put `alarm(1)` in the loop in your example, you'll call `alarm(1)` infinitely many times within a few microseconds of each invocation. And then [this](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=alarm&) happens:

> If an alarm has already been set with alarm() but has not been delivered, another call to alarm() will supersede the prior call.

I.e., the alarm gets cleared in each iteration of the loop. And since your loop runs forever, the alarm is never permanently set.

Comment: @downvoter Why the downvote? Genuinely interested to know as the answer seems good to me.

Comment: Aha ok! now I understand. But whats the point of waiting before sending an alarm anyways? I mean why do we always have to wait at least one second before sending an alarm?

Comment: @Elirovi In real life what is the point of setting an alarm to go off immediately since you are already awake? Same here. The whole point of an alarm is to wake you up *later*.

Comment: @kaylum Got it.